# php calling function dynamically returns null

Tags: php, reflection

Im trying to call a function dynamically, using call_user_func_array, but the issue I'm facing is that if the function returns boolean,Parameter variables are stored in an array, but if the function returns a string it will work fine

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a
>   valid callback, function  'equal' not found or invalid function
>   name not included in ...

```
$param = array (
   0 => Jill
   1 => Jack
);

echo call_user_func_array("equal", $param);

function equal($str, $str_2) {
     if ($str==$str_2) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: they are in same place or `equal` is included?

Comment: in other place, but calling functions that return a string works well .

Comment: He meant: Do you include the file contain `equal()` _before_ you call `call_user_func_array()`?

Comment: You say "it will produce an array", but then copy an error message saying that the function could not be found, which would make it return `NULL`, and demonstrate with `echo`, which would be an odd choice for a boolean or an array. Does the code as you've posted it actually reproduce the error for you?

Comment: edited it, I mean the parameters are stored in an array

Comment: Your `array()` syntax is wrong, but that shouldn't cause this error. Jack and Jill need to be in quotes, and you need a comma between them.

Comment: @Barmar that's a copy-paste of a print_r it's not meant to reproduce array syntax, just to show you what the array contains.

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters are stored in an array"? What is that a `print_r()` of? The input to the function, or the output?

Comment: call_user_func_array , requires the parameters to be in an array

Comment: Yes. That's why it's called call_user_func_ARRAY. RTFM http://php.net/call_user_func_array http://uk.php.net/call_user_func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your script. it is working and returning "false".
Just use var_dump() instead of echo to test it.
And if equal() is returning array then array is also returned. no errors for me.

Comment: Works for me, too, once I fix the array syntax problems.